smart card login without network
We have many branches that are connected to the headquarters (on-premise Windows domain) via the Internet (ADSL connection -> VPN). Users at the branch offices log into Windows using smart cards. But when the internet connection goes down, they are not able to log in and cannot work (no DC available for authentication) 
Is there any way to handle this situation ? Some kind of caching of credentials ?
I’m concerned about the Windows login itself, so that users can at least work in Word, Excel, etc. I don’t need to deal with temporary unavailability of domain resources.

Windows will automatically cache domain credentials but eventually the domain must be accessible. I would determine the reason these clients are unable to reach the domain and solve that problem. All this comes down to how the domain is verifying the certificate on these smart cards, in my personal experience, a client on a domain can be configured to validate the certificate itself.  However, eventually the CRL must be updated, otherwise a revoked certificate can access the domain.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsclient/forum/all/offline-smartcard-logon/57bc4035-e14d-4eb4-b0c0-6f5156ea4ac3 Windows already supports offline/disconnected login using domain credentials. I would guess that this includes smart card login. You should be looking at your Domain Policies to make sure that logins are cached, and at the Event Viewer to see what is actually failing during these offline login attempts.
